# datepicker not working and showing error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I implemented a date picker into my form, it was working and now its stopped working, I can't see where the problem is as the id match up and the script is correct.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      console.log('#datepicker');
  });
  </script>

 <tr>
 <td><li><label for="dob">DOB</label></li></td>
 <td><input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob"/></li></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: try to replace your reference with this and see what will happen `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
  `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you post the error message? Also check your <script></script> tags

Comment: Hi sorry by adding those libraries it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think this must have to do with the way you were loading your jQuery sources. You are missing an `li` tag on the second `td`. But this works for me.

```
<table> 
<tr>
 <td><li><label for="dob">DOB</label></li></td>
 <td><li><input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" name="dob"/></li></td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBm3R/1/